# saving user input on websites

Tags: javascript, html

i am making a website for my workplace and i need the content to remain on all the computers that access the site

i have the code for it and i just need to make it stay on the site

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='text' id='idea' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
<br>
<ul id='list'></ul>

<script>
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    //First things first, we need our text:
    var text = document.getElementById("idea").value; //.value gets input values

    //Now construct a quick list element
    var li = "<li>" + text + "&nbsp" + "<input type=checkbox>" + "Ready" + "</input>" + "&nbsp" + "<input type=text>" + "</input>" + "</li>";

    //Now use appendChild and add it to the list!
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += li;
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

so it would be amazing if someone can fins me an easy and simple solution.
Thank you

Comment: Google "localStorage"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Storage using Javascript / Jquery (Without using HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697752/local-storage-using-javascript-jquery-without-using-html5)

Comment: Wait... Do you mean that when one person enters some information on one computer, another person on **another computer** can see it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do it: You could use local storage to store the data on the user's machine. But keep in mind - the data will be deleted as soon as the user clears their local storage.

```
// Get stored text (undefined if nothing stored)
const storedIdea = localStorage.getItem("storedIdea");

// Store text
localStorage.setItem("storedIdea", text);
```

If you want something more persistent you'll have to use authentication and a backend (you could give Firebase a try!).

Answer (score 0):

Window.localStorage is what you can use to locally store data even after the page unloads. The data will remain, be accessible, and modifiable every time you load and unload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript object with the values you want to store.
(Can be an object or a single variable)

```
var userObj = {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "30"
}
```

Set the object or variable to the `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", userObj);
```

Use the same `userDetails` keyword to access the storage values.

```
var details = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
```